# node.js with child processes in docker

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-swarm, child-process

I have a node.js web application that runs on my amazon aws server using nginx and pm2. The application processes files for the user, which is done using a job system and child processes. In short, when the application starts via pm2, i create a child process for each cpu core of the server. Each child process (worker) then completes jobs from the job queue.

My question is, could i replicate this in docker or would i need to modify it somehow. One assumption i had was that i would need to create a container for the database, one container for the application, and then multiple worker containers to do the processing, so that if one crashes i just spin up another worker.

I have been doing research online, including a udemy course to get my head around this stuff, but i haven't come across an example or something i can relate to my problem/question.

Any help, reading material or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try also https://kubernetes.io/

Comment: i'm not sure that's really applicable here

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/coarse-parallel-processing-work-queue/ looks similar to your task

Comment: This question is likely to get closed as too broad. Yes, you could replicate the whole stack (application, database, workers) in a single Docker container. Yes, you could also set up an application with separate containers. Yes, you could use kubernetes to manage a set of containers. This is a question where there are many possible answers, each with many factors to consider and each with pros and cons. Stack Overflow is intended for specific questions related to programming.

Comment: I’ve read that running the whole thing in a Docker container has huge performance hits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Containers run at the same performance level as the host OS. There is no process performance hit. I created [a whitepaper with Docker and HPE on this](http://d.pr/f/Zjv65z/1BuMbZ8p).

You wouldn't use pm2 or nodemon, which are meant to start multiple processes of your node app and restart them if they fail. That's the job of Docker now.

If in Swarm, you'd just increase the replica count of your service to be similar to the number of CPU/threads you'd want to run at the same time in the swarm.

I don't mention the nodemon/pm2 thing for Swarm in my [node-docker-good-defaults](https://github.com/BretFisher/node-docker-good-defaults) so I'll at that as an issue to update it for.

Comment: if i used it in a swarm and set the replica count to the number of cpu cores. with the node application creating a worker for each cpu core. wouldn't that overload the system and/or reduce performance. I'm not sure but i think based on what suggestions/answers i have recieved so far and what i have understood so far of your udemy course. the best solution for me would be to split the workers into a seperate container from the main application and the replicate those so i have one worker per core. what are your thoughts?

Comment: Yes I would split those out into their own containers. I wouldn't assume it would "reduce performance" assuming you had enough memory to run all the containers. A properly coded node app wouldn't use much if any CPU when traffic isn't being sent to it.